# Datatable custom sort function on a given column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables and I need to sort data by the first column which contains checkboxes by displaying checked boxes first

```
oTable =  $('#userTable', context).dataTable(
{
    "sAjaxSource":'/ajax/getdata/',
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) 
    {
        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( 
        {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "POST",
            "url": sSource,
            "data": params,
            "success" :  function(data)
            {
                fnCallback(data);
                fnSortBySelected();
            } 
        });
    }
});

var fnSortBySelected = function()
{
    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
    var i = 0; 

    $('td:first-child input[type=checkbox]',oTable).sort(function(a, b)
    {
        if(a.checked) 
            oTable.fnUpdate( oSettings.aoData[i]._aData, i, 0);
        else 
            oTable.fnUpdate( oSettings.aoData[i+1]._aData, i, 0);
        i++;       
    });
}
```

---

thanks for your time , this is what i tried so far :

```
 oTable =  $('#userTable', context).dataTable({
"sAjaxSource":'/ajax/getdata/',
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
           "dataType": 'json',
           "type": "POST",
           "url": sSource,
           "data": params,
           "success" :  function(data){
               fnCallback(data);
               fnSortBySelected();
           } 
        } );
}

 });

var fnSortBySelected = function()
{
    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
    var i = 0; 

    $('td:first-child input[type=checkbox]',oTable).sort(function(a, b){
        if(a.checked) 
             oTable.fnUpdate( oSettings.aoData[i]._aData, i, 0);
        else 
             oTable.fnUpdate( oSettings.aoData[i+1]._aData, i, 0);
         i++;       
    } );


}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Providing your current code is a nice gesture saying that your not just asking for help and would like to learn.

Comment: Hi Nate , thanks for your time , this is what i tried so far :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Made it using Snickers answer by creating a hidden column (first column index 0) on every selected checkbox , i set the corresponding hidden column to "selected" then I sort the table on that hidden column   and first name column

to hide the first column use

```
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 0, false );
```

for every clicked checkbox do this

```
$('input[tyope=checkbox]',oTable).each(function(){
  var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition($(this).parents('tr:first').get(0));
  oTable.fnUpdate( 'selected',aPos, 0 );
  $(this).attr('checked', true);  
});
```

and then call

```
oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'desc'],[2,'asc']] );
```

Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just add the right aoColumnDefs for your column:

```
oTable =  $('#userTable', context).dataTable(
{
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ],
    .....
```

See [Datatables colums](http://datatables.net/usage/columns)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Sort immediately with columns 0 and 1
  oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
} );
```

Comment: Hey Snickers , your fnSort is working but it's not sorting column with checkboxes , any Idea what i can do ?